# How to add custom product relations via xml in Magento?

Tags: php, xml, magento

I already installed the "related products" plugin in my magento...and the related.phtml in included in right banner of the page by defalut via xml.here is the code-

```
<reference name="right">
        <block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related" before="-" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml"/>
    </reference>
```

Now i want the related products in right banner instead of i would like to add it in another place say, "view.phtml" page of product details. then how do i add this page via xml. Also if there is any other way to add the related products part in a specific place div i would like to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hello i think its not possible via xml but you will show on view page content

```
<reference name="content">
            <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">.....
<block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related"  template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </reference>
```

2.comment reference right
3.add in view.phtml where you want

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('catalog.product.related'); ?>
```

Hope this help you....